# Deeplink just opens application but does not print componet needed for action swift

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I added Universal Link to my project and done the whole process of uploading an associate file to my server. Tested and it is available. now I am trying to print a particular value but whenever I click the application, it only opens application. I tried printing some values on the console but they never get printed below is my code

```
extension AppDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
            let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
                return false
        }
        log("DEEP :LINK 1 \(components)", .fuck)
        log("DEEP :LINK 2 \(components.url)", .fuck)
        log("DEEP :LINK 3 \(Int(components.url?.lastPathComponent ?? "0"))", .fuck)
//        presentDetailViewController(Int(components.url?.lastPathComponent ?? "0") ?? 0)
        NotificationEvent.id.accept(Int(components.url?.lastPathComponent ?? "0") ?? 0)
        NotificationEvent.isFromNotification.accept(true)
        if let webpageUrl = URL(string: "https://example.com") {
            log("DEEP :LINK 1 weby \(webpageUrl)", .fuck)
            application.open(webpageUrl)
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You try use

```
print("something")
```

instead of

```
log("something")
```

?